# symfony 2 , 500 Internal Server Error, render js file

Tags: php, symfony, twig, production-environment

Sorry my writing, I'm from Brazil.

I've got this error when I try to use my system in the 'prod' environment.
On 'dev' environment everything works just fine. 
On 'prod' environment does not always give the error. The error appears randomly.

```
GET http://192.168.1.54/erp-zyx/web/publico/js/jquery/datepicker_custom.js 500 (Internal Server Error) 192.168.1.54/:631
```

In my base.html.twig:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{path("datepicker_custom")}}"></script>`

In my Controller:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/js/jquery/datepicker_custom.js", name="datepicker_custom")
 */
public function datepickerCustomAction()
{
    $response = $this->render('ZuniAdminBundle:Plugin:datepicker_custom.js.twig', array());
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');
    return $response;
}
```

When I put 'true' in app.php `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);`, the 'prod' environment everything works just fine. But I can´t put true on debug.

The log write this:

`[2014-03-05 10:20:32] request.INFO: Matched route "datepicker_custom" (parameters: "_controller": "Zuni\AdminBundle\Controller\PluginController::datepickerCustomAction", "_route": "datepicker_custom") [] []
[2014-03-05 10:20:33] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Could not write new cache file to C:/xampp/htdocs/erp-zyx/app/cache/prod/jms_diextra/metadata/.cache.php." at C:\xampp\htdocs\erp-zyx\vendor\jms\metadata\src\Metadata\Cache\FileCache.php line 48 {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException: Could not write new cache file to C:/xampp/htdocs/erp-zyx/app/cache/prod/jms_diextra/metadata/.cache.php. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\erp-zyx\\vendor\\jms\\metadata\\src\\Metadata\\Cache\\FileCache.php:48)"} []`

I've tried everything I could. This happens with four js files I render at the server.
Thank you!

Comment: Use a VM instead of windows to test websites. WAMP (Windows Apache MySQL PHP) setup is notorious for being weird, not to mention slow as hell.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with tinymce.min.js

Comment: @MarioJohnathan You could solve? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah! I had `<?` and `?>` in my tinymce.min.js and my server didn't like it. I change them to `&lt;?` and `?&gt;` and everything worked well

Comment: The initial code was `pi:function(e,t){t?r.push("<?",e," ",t,"?>"):r.push("<?",e,"?>")`

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear cache:

```
app/console cache:clear --env=dev --no-debug
```

Comment: not to clear the **dev** mode you have to clear **prod** mode

Answer (score 0):

By reading your log, I think you should add a `chmod 777` to your "prod" folder and "cache" folder